# Same ID on SQL Server and Oracle but don't match

Tags: sql-server, oracle, linked-server

I have a SQL Server table A, Oracle table B, and ID '123456'

```
SELECT * FROM table A WHERE ID = '123456' --return record without issue
SELECT * FROM table B WHERE ID = '123456' --return record without issue
```

but when I use linked server to do the below query:

```
SELECT * FROM table A WHERE ID = (SELECT ID FROM table B WHERE ID = '123456') --nothing return
```

I have ensured there is no blank space issue in the column

More weird, I have totally 340k records, only 10k records have such issue, for the remaining 330k I can pull without issue.

What could be the possible cause? Thanks!

Comment: Why do you have numbers in quotes - why not `= 123456`? Are they stored as numbers or strings? If they are stored as strings, are they the same datatype, specifically char vs. varchar?

Comment: what is type of ID in `tableA` and what is type in `tableB`? How are linked databases?

Comment: I finally troubleshoot it. That's because of case issue. Say if the ID is '123ABC' in table A, and '123abc' in table B.

when you do 

SELECT * FROM table A WHERE ID = '123abc' it still returns record

but when you do

SELECT * FROM table B WHERE ID IN (SELECT ID FROM table B WHERE ID = '123ABC') no record

I have to add lower(ID) to it. Thanks guys!